# Php fatal error when truncating

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to truncate a table in my database. The error I get is

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on boolean in /var/www/html/rubynetwork_servers/truncate.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/rubynetwork_servers/truncate.php on line 4

I have tried allsorts including looking on stackoverflow for the answers. My code is

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","-snip-","ruby");
    $sql = "truncate table ruby_servers";
    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
?>
```

Comment: the connection fails, so `$con` is false.

Comment: the connection is fine for me?

Comment: do a `var_dump($con);` - I bet it's false.

Comment: mhm. says false.... but it works because in other settings it works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the mode you are programming. The right working code will be:

```
<?
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "databasename");
    $sql= "TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_name";
    //$mysqli->query($sql)                // this will execute query
                                    // Your checking conditions here.
    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Please note the way I have used 'new'. It is required by object-oriented way of programming.

You are applying object-oriented way to code to procedural mode.

'->' can only be used when you have a "new" object. So, use new.

Don't forget to close the connection after using it.

If it's still hard for you to understand then you may still use procedural mode of mysqli extension. Please don't use old mysql extension in new projects.

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: What PHP error_log says about my given code? One thing is still there, you have to use 'new' for object oriented programming.